# Why does the doc say `__index` is looked up in the table?

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

From the [Lua 5.3 doc](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4):

> **`__index`:** The indexing access `table[key]`. ... The metamethod is looked up in `table`.

It says the same thing for `__newindex`, but not for any other metamethod.

If this were true (which it's not), it would be a major departure from previous versions of Lua. The following code outputs `nil`, as I would expect, but it's inconsistent with the doc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua5.3

local proto = {a = 54}
local t0 = {__index = proto}
print(t0.a)
```

To be clear: If the doc was correct, I would expect `t0` in the above code to only require an `__index` field without an actual metatable for `t0.a` to be `54`. So does anyone know what's going on with the doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly interpreting the meaning of the term. To say that it is "metamethod `Y` is looked up in X" does not mean that it searches the X table for an entry named `Y`. It means that it gets the metatable for X and looks up an entry named `Y`, as if by `rawget(getmetatable(X) or {}, "Y")`, as specified in the docs.

This terminology is repeatedly used in the metamethod descriptions. For example:

> First, Lua will check the first operand (even if it is valid). If that operand does not define a metamethod for `__add`, then Lua will check the second operand.

It's not asking if the first (or second) operand have a method `__add`; it asks if they have a *metamethod* `__add`.

As you can see from the `__add` example, you have to specify which of the operands it tries to get metamethods from, and in which order. For `table[key]`, the point of the text is that doesn't try to get the metamethod from `key`, only from `table`. That may seem a tad bit obvious, but completeness is better than incompleteness.